# php xdebug in netbeans - how to see values of variable?

Tags: php, python, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I have enabled `xdebug` in `php.ini` file as follows:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
```

and my netbeans setting is the same as their manual. Now when I try Ctrl+F5 (After setting breakpoint in line 140) then it shows as follows:

[image: breakpoint setted in line 140]

How can I see the value of `$user_id`(or any other variable's value) in netbean's console below??

**or Is there are any way available to debug PHP code by setting breakpoint and inspect variable value in CLI** like python `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`??? so that code break in particular line (When action taken like submit form or reload browser) and then I can inspect each variable before breakpoint even `continue` after breakpoint

Comment: Xdebug isn't set up / working properly ("Waiting for connection"), please re-check your settings. remote_enable should probably be enabled. And make sure you start the xdebug session properly in the browser. http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: remote enabled, now issue is breakpoint stopping code execution in core library's (CodeIgniter) first line but i set breakpoint in my custom controller

Comment: Either disable "break on first line" in your IDE or just hit play to go to the next break point.

Comment: helped. Now how can I set breakpoint and review variables on browser reload?? suppose on submit want to set breakpoint

Comment: I had some problems with netbeans too, especially debugging magento in it, Using xdebug helper in chrome (extension) did the trick, make sure to right click the icon and set that you are using netbeans.

Comment: I have written a step by step article to set it up in Eclipse. It should be very similar. Pls take a look here http://www.bizmate.biz/articles-mainmenu-2/18-little-it-tricks/47-xdebug-php-debugging-xampp-esclipse

Answer (score 0):

1.Review your php.ini configuration.

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Also make sure your zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll" is correct. On my computer I have / instead of \, not sure if it matters...

2.Restart your server (not sure if needed).

3.Check your netbeans configuration in Tools->options->PHP->Debugging

4.Check you project properties : "Browser" and "Run Configuration"

If everything is correct, you can set a break point within netbeans and laung debug: "Debug"->"Debug project"

Comment: Tested as you wrote, even with several config. same as image given in question

Comment: Do you launch debug via netbeans ? Also: in the screenshot you can see "Waiting for connection" so xdebug seems to be misconfigured. Check your logs